# How to get only most recents objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have an option object that contains a list of options that I keep track of.
I would like to retrieve the most recent values of this option.

My model:

```py
class MachineOption(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    value_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    machine = models.ForeignKey(
        "machine.Machine",
        verbose_name=_("machine"),
        related_name="machine_options",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )  

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("MachineOption")
        verbose_name_plural = _("MachineOptions")
        ordering = ["machine", "name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Each time the value of an option must be modified, I don't overwrite the previous value but I add a new MachineOption object which will have the most recent date_time.

I can retrieve the value of a single most recent option with this request:
`MachineOption.objects.filter(name="threshold temp").latest("date_time")`

But I don't know how to get the values of all the most recent options.
For example, I can have 4 objects:

```json
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "name",
            "value": "m1",
            "value_type": "string",
            "date_time": "2021-09-17T07:12:15.446282Z",
            "machine": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "name",
            "value": "m1.0",
            "value_type": "string",
            "date_time": "2021-09-17T07:12:19.904487Z",
            "machine": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "threshold temp",
            "value": "20",
            "value_type": "int",
            "date_time": "2021-09-17T06:57:37.881934Z",
            "machine": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "threshold temp",
            "value": "30",
            "value_type": "int",
            "date_time": "2021-09-17T07:12:06.128011Z",
            "machine": 1
        }
```

I want to be able to retrieve the most recent "threshold temp" option and also the most recent "name" with a single query.
I want to be able to retrieve:

```json
       {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "name",
            "value": "m1.0",
            "value_type": "string",
            "date_time": "2021-09-17T07:12:19.904487Z",
            "machine": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "threshold temp",
            "value": "30",
            "value_type": "int",
            "date_time": "2021-09-17T07:12:06.128011Z",
            "machine": 1
        }
```

Is this possible or do I have to make a request for each different option?

Comment: Are you using a `PostGres` database?

Comment: Yes I am using postgresql

Comment: try `MachineOption.objects.order_by('-date_time').distinct('name')`

Comment: I got an error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("machine_machineoption"."name") "machine...`

Comment: It's works with: `MachineOption.objects.order_by('name', '-date_time').distinct("name")`

Comment: ah, Good stuff!